Inverse direction of Hodge index theorem
The Hodge index theorem states that the intersection matrix associated to curves on a smooth algebraic surface has a specified signature---namely, if the intersection matrix has size $n \times n$ then it has signature $(1, n-1)$, meaning it has 1 positive eigenvalue and $(n-1)$ negative eigenvalues.
This gives a fairly strong restriction on matrices that come from the intersection pairing on some surface.
What is known about the "inverse" direction of this problem?
If we write down some symmetric, integer-valued matrix $M$ whose signature is $(1, n-1)$, does there exist some smooth algebraic surface $X$ whose intersection matrix is $M$?
Any information or references would be appreciated.

For a more concrete sub-question, is there a smooth algebraic surface whose intersection matrix is the following one?
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Cross-posted on Mathoverflow.

Is this intersection pairing unimodular?

The pairing on algebraic cycles need not to be unimodular.

Ah, @Sasha, good point. Thanks.
